# last fgets in a loop never executes

Tags: c

I am trying to populate 2 arrays using fgets. For some reason, the last fget of the last loop iteration never executes.

For example, if num_inputs = 5, only 9 lines are read (instead of 10).

```
int num_imputs;

//read the number of inputs

scanf("%d", &num_imputs);

char secret_arr[num_imputs][8];//stores all the secrets
char encoded_message_arr[num_imputs][256];//stores all the encoded messages

for(int i = 0; i < num_imputs ; i++){

    fgets (secret_arr[i],8, stdin);
    fgets (encoded_message_arr[i],256, stdin);

}
```

This code works perfectly find if I hardcode num_inputs instead of reading it using scanf(). Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a newline in `scanf` (assuming your input has an ENTER for the `num_inputs` data entry). Results in the first fgets actually storing an empty string as it stops when it sees the newline that was part of the `num_inputs` data entry.

Should be:

```
scanf("%d\n", &num_imputs);
```

Comment: That worked thank you! Just out of curiosity, Can you explain why it always missed the last fget of the last loop iteration?

Comment: Right, cause the newline character doesn't only specify the end of the integer or whatever is the input but it's also stored in a buffer. It is not automatically consumed. Fgets reads n input characters from the buffer until a newline is found. In your case the first character is the newline character that has been left in the buffer, so you get the string "\n".

Comment: @SivaDotRender Easiest way to understand it is with an example. Assume num_inputs is 1. Then the first fgets will immediately read the newline. Then next fgets will read the secret (instead of the encoded_message). At that point the loop ends and you've ended up having one extra line of input that was not read.

Comment: ah makes perfect sense! Thank you!